# How to optimize large lang.json files to reduce the bundle size

Tags: reactjs, bundle

I used a auto translation script to update my lang.json file to support 36 languages.

e.g of one of the entries in my lang.json file

```
"reports": {
    "en-us": {
      "text": "Reports"
    },
    "da": {
      "text": "Rappoter"
    },
    "hr": {
      "text": "Izvještaji"
    },
    "sv": {
      "text": "Rapporter"
    },
    "sq": {
      "text": "Raportet"
    },
    "ar": {
      "text": "تقارير"
    },
    "bg": {
      "text": "Доклади"
    },
    "zh": {
      "text": "报告"
    },
    "nl": {
      "text": "Verslagen"
    },
    "et": {
      "text": "Aruanded"
    },
    "fi": {
      "text": "raportit"
    },
    "fr": {
      "text": "Rapports"
    },
    "ka": {
      "text": "ანგარიშები"
    },
    "de": {
      "text": "Berichte"
    },
    "it": {
      "text": "Rapporti"
    },
    "he": {
      "text": "דוחות"
    },
    "hi": {
      "text": "रिपोर्ट"
    },
    "es-mx": {
      "text": "Reportes"
    },
    "hu": {
      "text": "Jelentések"
    },
    "id": {
      "text": "Laporan"
    },
    "ja": {
      "text": "レポート"
    },
    "ko": {
      "text": "보고서"
    },
    "lv": {
      "text": "Ziņojumi"
    },
    "no": {
      "text": "Rapporter"
    },
    "pl": {
      "text": "Sprawozdania"
    },
    "pt": {
      "text": "Relatórios"
    },
    "ro": {
      "text": "rapoarte"
    },
    "ru": {
      "text": "Доклады"
    },
    "sr": {
      "text": "Izveštaji"
    },
    "sk": {
      "text": "Správy"
    },
    "sl": {
      "text": "Poročila"
    },
    "es": {
      "text": "Informes"
    },
    "ta": {
      "text": "அறிக்கைகள்"
    },
    "th": {
      "text": "รายงาน"
    },
    "tr": {
      "text": "Raporlar"
    },
    "uk": {
      "text": "Звіти"
    },
    "vi": {
      "text": "Báo cáo"
    }
  },
```

So the problem that i am facing is after the translation each and every string to 36 languages, my json file became tremendously large `i.e. 66000 lines` currently.

And this huge file is increasing the bundle size of my app.

[image]

As you can see the lang file is taking 1.33 MB in my bundle size.

Is there any way i can reduce the impact of the the lang file in my bundle size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have quite a lot of text. I'd include in the bundle only the most likely languages given your userbase (whether that's only English, or English and something else, etc). If a user does *not* read the given language and wants to change it, make an XHR request to the server to download whichever language they want instead, and update the UI with the new language after the request has finished.

In other words, serve the less-common languages only on demand, rather than with the main bundle.

You might also examine the IP of the user and serve their likely language(s) if you don't want an additional round-trip request after initial page load.